# Is there a German word for immense relief after a great work or effort?

Tags: phrase-request

Such as spending many hours or days on a great task, and when finished having an immense sens of relief, or a lightening of load?

Comment: Discussion on whether this question should be closed has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107524/discussion-on-question-by-welt-is-there-a-german-word-for-immense-relief-after-a). If you want to take this any further, please take it to [meta].

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Please [edit] your question to clarify: 1) You originally tagged this with *translation* and *english-to-german,* but there is no English term to be translated. Do you have a particular English term in mind that you want to translate? 2) Are you looking for a phrase to be said by the person who is relieved or are you looking for an expression that describes the relief itself. It may help to provide a specific sentence with a gap where you would use the phrase in question.

Comment: Please add context: in what situation in life do you want to use this? Is it for a written text, e.g. a shortstory or novel? Is it for use in everyday casual oral communication? Etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is not just one word for "immense relief". The German word for relief is "Erleichterung". There are many adjectives for immense such as immense, enorm, ungeheuer, gewaltig, riesig, and große. So I would say "immense Erleichterung" or "große Erleichterung".

For your example, you might say in English: "After a great ordeal it is an immense relief to be finished!" which would be in German: "Nach einer großen Tortur ist es eine große Erleichterung, fertig zu sein!" Personally, I would say: "After a great ordeal I'm immensely relieved it is finished!" which would be "Nach einer großen Tortur bin ich sehr erleichtert, dass es fertig ist!"

Or for just the statement: "It is an immense relief to be finished!" would be "Es ist eine große Erleichterung, fertig zu sein!"

Answer (score 2):

Puh, geschafft !

I am a German native speaker and would say "Mir fällt eine Last von den Schultern." is good German but not exact what you want, this is more like to say "Now I got rid of a big burdon, before I thought I cannot make it". But not every days work is like this -- this is too much.

"spitze Gefühl" this is not good German, you need to say "Spitzengefühl". Germans concatinate a lot of words to a new word. The best example is something like this "Trammbahnschinenritzenreiniger" or "Donaudampfschifffahrtskapitän". But never the less, this is what the first intention of the phrase of this question means. While the "Last von den Schultern" is too much, this is not enough. It only says that you feel good now for the upcoming event, but it says nothing about your hard work of the day. And where is there should be an event to day this. Simply relaxing is not the reason somebody says this.

Comment: ["Puh, geschafft", sagt Michael Kellner, der Bundesgeschäftsführer, ganz am Schluss.](https://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/loesung-in-der-not-a-e375a90e-2cb3-4d9e-ad29-11d96ae80179) (article about the first digital party convention of [The Greens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Greens_–_The_Green_Alternative) - published a few hour prior to the answer)

Comment: Sorry, I linked to the Austrian party - and not the German [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliance_90/The_Greens).

Comment: I think he would only say (or write) this in private group, not for business or political speech.

Comment: I don't know how to say this as one idiomatic expression in a political speech.  once Angela Merkel said  "wir schaffen das", this is related to it, and she earned a shitstorm for it and never uses it again in a speech.

Answer (score 0):

Dependending on the context you could say

> Mir fällt eine Last von den Schultern.

Comment: I must say, while this is a valid interpretation, it could use some more wording, and 1 or 2 alternatives, like for instance "große Erleichtering".

Answer (score 0):

If you are at the end of the work day, you'd say

```
Feierabend!

Genug für heute!
```